# VB: An error occurred in the secure channel support

Tags: xml, vba, ssl, httprequest

I have VBA code in Excel Template. It creates HTTP request and send XML to servers. While sending the data it gives error like `"Error occurred in secure channel support"`.

We have Windows 10 machine, Excel 2016. TLS 1.2 check box enabled.

```vb
Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xHTTP As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Set xHTTP= New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
xHTTP.Open "POST" url False
Xml content code....

xHTTP.send xDoc.XML
strResponse=  xHTTP.responseText
```

Please help me on this